Why does my notification assistant change to "alarms only" automatically?
My notification assistant/wizard in windows 10 automatically switches to "Alerts only" without me setting it. I have to set it back to "Priority only" manually. After a few minutes of working on the PC, the assistant switches back to "Alerts only". Why does this happen? I want it to stay on "Priority only".


Is there more than one user? Try doing it as Admin user. Also, see if a Group Policy sets it: https://community.spiceworks.com/t/how-to-manage-windows-10-notifications-via-gpo-for-specific-programs/756487
